# How can I access the DOM of a page with MP4 extention?

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to access the DOM inside the page with MP4 extention, the page is not video nor audio, it is simply an html with just MP4 extention "http://playbb.me/embed.php?w=600&h=438&vid=at/nw/sore_ga_seiyuu_-_10.mp4". Below is the code I am using to gain access to it using Simple HTML DOM. This strategy works on other URL except the ones that has extention like this. It just gives me blank page.

```
$url= "http://playbb.me/embed.php?w=600&h=438&vid=at/nw/sore_ga_seiyuu_-_10.mp4";

    $url_link = urldecode($url);
    $html = file_get_html($url_link);

    $raw_html = $html->find('body', 0)->innertext;

    echo $raw_html;
```

Comment: The URL doesn't have a ".mp4" extension. URLs don't have extensions, at least not ones that are remotely relevant. The content-type of the document is `text/html`, that is what matters.

Comment: That code doesn't give a blank page when I run it. I can't reproduce your problem. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMQJx1vdGJEV5RdCbFsta3QLNVoIhVOO_I

Comment: Why are you decoding the data in the URL? Surely `file_get_html` expects to be passed a valid URL? Not one with all the escaped characters decoded.

Comment: It is working here. Possibly you've just got your IP address blacklisted by the server. Whatever the problem is, it isn't revealed by the code in the question.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet

Comment: A snippet of what? How to unplug your computer and physically move it to a different network?! **There is nothing significant wrong with the code you already have!**

Comment: This is the result I am looking for, use this url "http://videowing.me/embed/c35d98860f7fc8617bb035eacdececdf?w=600&#038;h=438". You will see the difference

Comment: The output of the script when given the two different URLs is very similar. So no, I don't see the difference. You described the output you were getting as "blank", when I run the script it clearly is not blank (see again the screenshot above).

Comment: Do you see the video in your browser?

Comment: On the first url I gave you?

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with PHP getting "a blank result"? I see the code to load the video in the output of the PHP program.

Comment: if you try $url= "http://playbb.me/embed.php?w=600&h=438&vid=at/nw/sore_ga_seiyuu_-_10.mp4"; THEN try $url = 'http://videowing.me/embed/c35d98860f7fc8617bb035eacdececdf?w=600&#038;h=438'; The 1st URL won't display anything in the browser while the 2nd url will display the video. Also if you check the source code, the 1st url has an empty content inside of id="flowplayer" which what I need while the 2nd url has something in it.

Comment: No. Both continue to display the video for me.

Comment: Can you post the code you have there for http://playbb.me/embed.php?w=600&h=438&vid=at/nw/sore_ga_seiyuu_-_10.mp4%22 ' url to make it work. Maybe I am just missing something

Comment: It's identical to the code you have in the question except the URL is different and I added an `include` for the PHP DOM library you are using.

Comment: No way, it is giving me a blank page on playbb.me, the other one works fine though. The video is not displaying on the browser

Comment: I refer you, once again, to the screenshot showing your code and the (non-blank) result of running that code. **The problem is something other than the code**

Comment: I see code like the screenshot you posted, but do you ever see the video displaying??? for http://playbb.me/embed.php?w=600&h=438&vid=at/nw/sore_ga_seiyuu_-_10.mp4%22

Comment: Oh good grief. Your question is about why the HTML document you get from running the PHP script doesn't run the video? So you aren't getting a blank response from it, the rendered HTML document doesn't show anything?

Comment: Did I mentioned at the top "blank page" not blank of source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy the **body** of that HTML document (`$html->find('body', 0)->innertext;`), you aren't copying anything outside the body.

Look at the Developer Tools Console in your browser when you load the document.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

- The script in the body depends on jQuery.
- jQuery is loaded in the head
- You are discarding the head and returning only the content of the body

Comment: Thanks bro, that's the problem, I was trying to get the content inside the body which is empty on the first place, I change it to html and everything works like a charm

Comment: No. The body is not empty. It contains a script. That script depends on jQuery. jQuery is loaded by the head.

Comment: I change it to $html->find('html', 0)->innertext and everything works great! Thanks again!